# i want to create a mobile compatible dynamic menu using c#?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to create a dynamic menu using c# and sql server but in mobile compatible mode. my code is working fine but i want this code mobile compatible.please suggest ..

My code is.

```
    public string RenderMenuPermissions(int userRecNo)
    {
        try
        {
            string MenuHTML = "";
            string BaseURL = "";

            TBL_MASTER_MENU_PERMISSIONDAO oTBL_MASTER_MENU_PERMISSIONDAO = new TBL_MASTER_MENU_PERMISSIONDAO();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds = oTBL_MASTER_MENU_PERMISSIONDAO.GetMenuDetails(userRecNo, ref oTBL_LOG_ERRORSEntity);

            DataView dv = new DataView(ds.Tables[0]);

            BaseURL = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BaseURL"].ToString();
            int i, zz = 0;

            MenuHTML += Environment.NewLine + "<ul id='nav'>" + Environment.NewLine;
            int val = 0;
            i = 0;
            MenuHTML += "<li> <a href='" + BaseURL + "/" + "Default.aspx'>Home</a></li>" + Environment.NewLine;
            int parentID = -1;
            ///int childParentID = -1;
            int count = 0;
            int count3Level = 0;
            foreach (DataRowView drv in dv)
            {
                if (Convert.ToInt16(drv["PARENT_ID"]) == 0)
                {
                    val = val + 1;
                    if (zz == 1)
                    {
                        if (count == -1)    //in case their are no 1st level submenu after 2nd level submenu for same parentID
                        {
                            if (count3Level == 3)
                            {
                                MenuHTML += "</ul></li>" + Environment.NewLine;
                                count3Level = 0;
                            }
                            MenuHTML += "</ul></li>" + Environment.NewLine;
                            MenuHTML += "</a></ul></li>";
                            count = 0;
                            zz = 0;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                           // MenuHTML += "</a></li></ul></li>";
                            MenuHTML += "</a></ul></li>";
                            zz = 0;
                            count = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    MenuHTML += Environment.NewLine + "<li>" + Environment.NewLine;
                    MenuHTML += "<a href=\"" + drv["MENU_URL"].ToString() + "\" >";
                    MenuHTML += drv["MENU_NAME"].ToString() + "</a>" + Environment.NewLine;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (zz == 0)
                    {
                        MenuHTML += "<ul>" + Environment.NewLine;  //create dropdown for main tab in menu
                        parentID = Convert.ToInt16(drv["PARENT_ID"]);

                    }
                    if ((Convert.ToInt16(drv["PARENT_ID"]) != 0) && (Convert.ToInt16(drv["PARENT_ID"]) == parentID))
                    {
                        if (count == -1)    //in case their are  1st level submenu after 2nd level submenu for a given submenu for same parentID
                        {
                            if (count3Level == 3)
                            {
                                MenuHTML += "</ul></li>" + Environment.NewLine;
                                count3Level = 0;
                            }
                            MenuHTML += "</ul></li>" + Environment.NewLine;
                            count = 0;
                        }
                        else if (count >= 1) //close <a> tag for each submenu item 
                        {
                            MenuHTML += "</a></li>" + Environment.NewLine;
                            count = 0;
                        }
                        //MenuHTML += "<li><a href='" + BaseURL + "/" + drv["MENU_URL"].ToString() + "'>" + drv["MENU_NAME"].ToString() + "</a>";
                        MenuHTML += "<li><a id='" + drv["MENU_ID"].ToString() + "' href='" + BaseURL + "/" + drv["MENU_URL"].ToString() + "'>" + drv["MENU_NAME"].ToString();
                        zz = 1;
                        count++;
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        //generate 2nd level submenu
                        // MenuHTML += "</li>" + Environment.NewLine;
                        if (count >= 1)
                        {
                            MenuHTML += "<img src=\"" + BaseURL + "/images/arrow-right8.gif\" style=\"border-width:0px;vertical-align:middle\"  align=\"right\" alt=\"\"/></a>" + Environment.NewLine;
                            MenuHTML += "<ul>" + Environment.NewLine;
                            MenuHTML += "<li><a id='" + drv["PARENT_ID"].ToString() + "' href='" + BaseURL + "/" + drv["MENU_URL"].ToString() + "' style =\"border-top:solid 1px #0f62ac;\">" + drv["MENU_NAME"].ToString() + "</a></li>" + Environment.NewLine;

                            count = -1;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (drv["MENU_URL"].ToString() == "#")
                            {
                                MenuHTML += "<li><a id='" + drv["PARENT_ID"].ToString() + "' href='" + drv["MENU_URL"].ToString() + "' >" + drv["MENU_NAME"].ToString() + "<imgCompReq src=\"" + BaseURL + "/images/arrow-right8.gif\" style=\"border-width:0px;vertical-align:middle\"  align=\"right\" alt=\"\"/></a>";
                                MenuHTML += "<ul>" + Environment.NewLine;
                                count3Level = 1;

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (count3Level == 1)
                                {
                                    MenuHTML += "<li><a id='" + drv["PARENT_ID"].ToString() + "' href='" + BaseURL + "/" + drv["MENU_URL"].ToString() + "' style =\"border-top:solid 1px #0f62ac;\">" + drv["MENU_NAME"].ToString() + "</a></li>" + Environment.NewLine;
                                    count3Level = 3;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    MenuHTML += "<li><a id='" + drv["PARENT_ID"].ToString() + "' href='" + BaseURL + "/" + drv["MENU_URL"].ToString() + "'>" + drv["MENU_NAME"].ToString() + "</a></li>" + Environment.NewLine;
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }


            if (count >= 1)
            {
                MenuHTML += "</a></li>";
            }
            MenuHTML += "</ul>" + Environment.NewLine + "</ul>";

            MenuHTML = MenuHTML.Replace(BaseURL + "/#", "#"); //MenuHTML.Replace("/GCTS/#", "#");
            return MenuHTML;
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (oTBL_LOG_ERRORSEntity == null)
            {
                oTBL_LOG_ERRORSEntity = new TBL_LOG_ERRORSEntity();
                oTBL_LOG_ERRORSEntity.FUNCTION_NAME = "RenderMenuPermissions";
                oTBL_LOG_ERRORSEntity.MODULE_NAME = "PageClass";
                oTBL_LOG_ERRORSEntity.ERROR_TYPE = "Application";
                oTBL_LOG_ERRORSEntity.ERROR_DESC = ex.Message;
                CommonDAL.InsertException(oTBL_LOG_ERRORSEntity);
                oTBL_LOG_ERRORSEntity = null;

            }
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);


        }
    }
```

Comment: Sounds great!  You can do it

Comment: Very unclear what you are trying to achieve and how sql-server tag relates to constructing HTML shown in the post... (Side note: only handful of people can conastruct correct HTML by using string concatenation... Code shown in the post is unlikely written by one of them and hence produce invalid HTML)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov this function is working fine. my question is how i can convert this code in mobile compatible menu.this is working fine with laptops but not with mobiles..